# Bad request:Error function and timeout in ajax never fired

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here is my ajax call

```
var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "http://sample.com/customer/api/v1/meetings/meeting",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
          "x-api-key": token
        },
        "dataType":'json',
        "data": {
          "title": meetingData.title,
          "end_date": meetingData.endtdate,
          "from_date":  meetingData.startdate,
          "description": meetingData.description,
          "reminder_type": meetingData.remainder,
          "priority": meetingData.priority
        }
      }

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
},function(err){
   alert('error');
});
```

Problem is error callback function is never fired if any error is present.
Also i want to add a timeout this ajax call ,how can i do that??
I've added  `timeout:20000` parameter in my `settings` variable but the error call back is not fired

**UPDATE**

I will get a bad request error from the console ,how to solve that error??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt the `.done()` has a error callback, instead you should use `.then(successCB, errorCB)` which has both callbacks:

```
$.ajax(settings).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
},function(err){
   alert('error');
});
```

---

#### Update

As per updates: *I will get a bad request error from the console ,how to solve that error??*

Then in this case the doubtful entities could be your `data` object you are sending, one of them or more might have some data which is causing this error. So you can inspect what data is getting through here:

```
"data": {
      "title": meetingData.title,
      "end_date": meetingData.endtdate,
      "from_date":  meetingData.startdate,
      "description": meetingData.description,
      "reminder_type": meetingData.remainder,
      "priority": meetingData.priority
    }
```

Comment: Or use `done` for success and `fail` for failure (there is also an `always` that will be fired every time)

Comment: How can i add a timeout to this ??

Comment: Thanks:) now the error is showing one of my data parameter is missing thats why i am getting that error

Comment: @BlessanKurien great! glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Write `success` and `error` within `settings` variable itself:

```
var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "http://sample.com/customer/api/v1/meetings/meeting",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
          "x-api-key": token
        },
        "dataType":'json',
        "data": {
          "title": meetingData.title,
          "end_date": meetingData.endtdate,
          "from_date":  meetingData.startdate,
          "description": meetingData.description,
          "reminder_type": meetingData.remainder,
          "priority": meetingData.priority
        },
        "success":function(resp){
            //your work here
        },
        "error":function(resp){
            //your work here
        }
      }


$.ajax(settings);
```

Or remove it from settings and bind it globally to `document` as

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function( event, xhr) {
    //error code here
}).ajaxError(function(event,xhr){
   //error code here
});
```

Comment: I will get a bad request on post

Comment: Bad request?? What sort of?